# Limits of integration for a joint PDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}$ for 0 < x < y.

If I want to show that this is a joint PDF, I need to do a double integral and show that it is equal to 1. Do I set my integration limits up as 0,y and x,$\infty$ for x and y respectively?

Comment: Assuming that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0$ if $0 < x < y$ does not hold, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. One is: $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{y} \lambda^2\exp(-\lambda\cdot y)\,dx\,dy$$ and the other is:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{x}^{+\infty} \lambda^2\exp(-\lambda\cdot y)\,dy\,dx.$$

Comment: Can you please explain why my limits don't work? I assume that the domain is all points above the line y=x.

Comment: It works. The order suggested by Sergio Parreiras is simplest, but you can also integrate $x=0$ to $y$, $y=0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @Whistlekins: yes this is the domain (assuming we don't look at negative values of $x$ or $y$) and you can describe it as: 1) for every positive $y$ you consider all $x$_s below it or 2) for every positive $x$ you consider all $y$_s above it.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas: this was his original domain: $\int_{0}^y \int_{x}^{+\infty} \lambda^2 \exp(-\lambda\cdot y) \,dy\,dx$  which clearly does not work.

Comment: True. Integrating to $y$ in the second integral didn't even make sense.